# How to record a user has been registered to an event - SQLite

Tags: javascript, c#, sqlite, .net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to update an event within my calendar using https://fullcalendar.io/ to show if the current user is registered or not for that event to show that the event color will turn from green to red.

The below methods are within my service method.

```
        public List<TimeTableEvent> GetAllEvents()
        {
            return db.TimeTableEvents.ToList();
        }

        public List<EventAttendance> GetAllMembershipEvents(int membershipId)
        {
            var events = GetAllEvents();
            var attendances = db.Attendances.Where(m => m.MembershipId == membershipId);
            var membershipEvents = events.Select(e => new EventAttendance
            {
                Event = e,
                Attendance = attendances.FirstOrDefault(a => a.TimeTableEventId == e.Id)
            }).ToList();
            return membershipEvents;
        }

        public Attendance AddMembershipToEvent(int membershipId, int eventId)
        {
            var attendance = new Attendance { MembershipId = membershipId, TimeTableEventId = eventId, 
                AttendanceStatus = AttendanceStatus.Pending };
            db.Attendances.Add(attendance);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return attendance;
        }
```

I am then using this method within the controller

```
        public JsonResult GetMembershipEvents(int membershipId)
        {
            var events = service.GetAllMembershipEvents(membershipId);
            return Json(events);
        }
```

And then I have a javascript method within my View. That is shown below.

```
 function FetchEventsAndRenderCalendar() {
                var userId = 1;//User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Id");
                events = []; // clear existing events
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Timetable/GetMembershipEvents/" + userId,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, json) {
                            events.push(
                                {
                                    id: json.event.id,
                                    title: json.event.title,
                                    description: json.event.description,
                                    start: moment(json.event.start),
                                    end: moment(json.event.end),
                                    color: json.isRegistered?"Red":"Green",
                                    allDay: json.event.allDay
                                }
                            );
                        })
```

I am adding a user to an event so one of the events should be red when it complies. However, it is still showing as green.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you getting when you hit the same url from something like Postman?

Comment: I get this back:

`[
{
"event": {
"id": 1,
"title": "BJJ",
"description": "Learing BJJ",
"start": "2020-04-05T09:00:00",
"end": "2020-04-05T11:00:00",
"color": "Green",
"allDay": false
},
"attendance": null,
"isRegistered": false
},
{
"event": {
"id": 2,
"title": "Boxing",
"description": "boxing for begineers",
"start": "2020-04-05T10:00:00",
"end": "2020-04-05T11:00:00",
"color": "Green",
"allDay": false
},
"attendance": null,
"isRegistered": false
}
]`

Comment: Can you add `aync : false` in your call? See what headers you have on Postman and try to replicate that in the all when you make from the code.
Or better yet use a `promise` or `async-await `model to make a call.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm still a beginner at this. Where would this `async-await` be added within the code?

Comment: I will explain in an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing your function from this:

```
function FetchEventsAndRenderCalendar() {
                var userId = 1;//User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Id");
                events = []; // clear existing events
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Timetable/GetMembershipEvents/" + userId,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, json) {
                            events.push(
                                {
                                    id: json.event.id,
                                    title: json.event.title,
                                    description: json.event.description,
                                    start: moment(json.event.start),
                                    end: moment(json.event.end),
                                    color: json.isRegistered?"Red":"Green",
                                    allDay: json.event.allDay
                                }
                            );
                        })
```

to

```
// Function in which you use await should haveasync delaration
async function FetchEventsAndRenderCalendar() {
                var userId = 1;//User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Id");
                events = []; // clear existing events
    // await means wait for the call to finish and then proceed
    const response = await fetch('http://www.example.com/Timetable/GetMembershipEvents/' + userId, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}// Set required headers. Check Postman call you made.
    });
    console.log(response);
    //Continue doing stuff with response
}
```

Lot of nodejs projects do this. Try this. If this does not work, try adding `async: false` in your ajax call.

Comment: I've updated the code to this:

`async function FetchEventsAndRenderCalendar() {
                var userId = 1;//User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Id");
                events = []; // clear existing events
    const response = await fetch('https://localhost:44367/Timetable/GetMembershipEvents/' + userId, {
      method: 'GET',
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        // Set required headers. Check Postman call you made.
    });
    console.log(response);
    GenerateCalendar(response);
}`

Comment: This is the json response:

`[
{
"event": {
"id": 1,
"title": "BJJ",
"description": "Learing BJJ",
"start": "2020-04-05T09:00:00",
"end": "2020-04-05T11:00:00",
"color": "Green",
"allDay": false
},
"attendance": null,
"isRegistered": false
},
{
"event": {
"id": 2,
"title": "Boxing",
"description": "boxing for begineers",
"start": "2020-04-05T10:00:00",
"end": "2020-04-05T11:00:00",
"color": "Green",
"allDay": false
}
]`

Comment: Also tried adding the `async: false` but still printing out the same json response